# /data - Error: Failed to open the device

Tags: adb, storage, data

Device (Nook HD+) will not boot.

It was running LOS 14.1 with TWRP recovery, to which I can still boot up, but any attempts to wipe, or format the /data partition fail.

I also can access the shell (BusyBox) on the device through 'adb'. From there: `mkfs.f2fs /data` fails with `Error: failed to open the device`. I can format the underlying block device, but when I try to mount it, I get ...`failed: no such file or directory`.

And, that's all I know, and could use any and all pointers/advise if there's a way to recover from, what looks to me like, a corrupt storage. Is there a way?

Thanks

Edit: including terminal output:
#=========================

```
~ # ls
boot                       init.rc                    selinux_version
bootdata                   init.recovery.hlthchrg.rc  sepolicy
cache                      init.recovery.ovation.rc   service_contexts
charger                    init.recovery.service.rc   sideload
data                       init.recovery.usb.rc       supersu
default.prop               license                    sys
dev                        proc                       system
emmc                       property_contexts          tmp
etc                        recovery                   twres
external_sd                res                        ueventd.ovation.rc
file_contexts              root                       ueventd.rc
fstab.ovation              sbin
init                       seapp_contexts
~ # ls -la /data
__bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for localtime!
__bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
__bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for posixrules!
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x   22 root     root             0 May 11 21:47 ..
~ # mkfs.f2fs /data

        F2FS-tools: mkfs.f2fs Ver: 1.4.0 (2014-10-18) [modified by Motorola to reserve space]

Info: Debug level = 0
Info: Label =
Info: Segments per section = 1
Info: Sections per zone = 1
Info: Trim is enabled
        Error: Failed to open the device!
~ # mkfs.f2fs
        Error: Device not specified

Usage: mkfs.f2fs [options] device [sectors]
[options]:
  -a heap-based allocation [default:1]
  -d debug level [default:0]
  -e [extension list] e.g. "mp3,gif,mov"
  -l label
  -o overprovision ratio [default:5]
  -O set feature
  -q quiet mode
  -s # of segments per section [default:1]
  -z # of sections per zone [default:1]
  -t 0: nodiscard, 1: discard [default:1]
  -r reserved_bytes [default:0]
     (use only device_size-reserved_bytes for filesystem)
sectors: number of sectors. [default: determined by device size]
~ # cat /fstab.ovation
# Android fstab file for emmc-based device
#<src>                                                  <mnt_point> <type> <mnt_flags and options>                                  <fs_mgr_flags>
# The filesystem that contains the filesystem checker binary (typically /system) cannot
# specify MF_CHECK, and must come before any filesystems that do specify MF_CHECK
/dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/system    /system     ext4   ro,errors=panic                                          wait
/dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/userdata  /data       f2fs   rw,discard,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,inline_xattr  wait,nonremovable,check,encryptable=footer,length=-16384
/dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/userdata  /data       ext4   rw,discard,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic             wait,check,encryptable=footer,length=-16384
/dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/cache     /cache      ext4   rw,discard,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic             wait,check
/dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/rom       /rom        vfat   rw,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=117,dmask=007  defaults
/devices/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc1       auto        auto   defaults                                                 voldmanaged=sdcard1:auto
/dev/block/mmcblk0p4                                    /boot       emmc   defaults                                                 defaults
/dev/block/mmcblk0p3                                    /recovery   emmc   defaults                                                 defaults
/dev/block/mmcblk0p6                                    /bootdata   vfat   rw,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=117,dmask=007  defaults
/devices/platform/omap/musb-omap2430/musb-hdrc/usb1/1-1 auto        auto   defaults                                                 voldmanaged=usb0:auto
/dev/block/zram0                                        none        swap   defaults                                                 zramsize=67108864
~ # ls /dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/userdata
/dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/userdata
~ # ls /dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/
boot        bootloader  factory     rom         userdata
bootdata    cache       recovery    system      xloader
~ # mkfs.f2fs /dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/userdata

        F2FS-tools: mkfs.f2fs Ver: 1.4.0 (2014-10-18) [modified by Motorola to reserve space]

Info: Debug level = 0
Info: Label =
Info: Segments per section = 1
Info: Sections per zone = 1
Info: Trim is enabled
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 27000832 (13184 MB)
Info: zone aligned segment0 blkaddr: 512
Info: format version with
  "Linux version 3.0.31-ovation-green+ (green@fatbox1.localnet) (gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC) ) #2 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jun 17 01:18:23 EDT 2013"
Info: Discarding device: 3199798464 sectors
Info: Overprovision ratio = 2%
Info: Overprovision segments = 236 (GC reserved = 108)
Info: format successful
~ # mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/block/mmcblk1p1 on /external_sd type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p9 on /cache type ext4 (rw,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered)
~ # mount -h
mount: invalid option -- h
BusyBox v1.22.1 bionic (2017-12-10 05:05 +0000) multi-call binary.

Usage: mount [OPTIONS] [-o OPTS] DEVICE NODE

Mount a filesystem. Filesystem autodetection requires /proc.

        -a              Mount all filesystems in fstab
        -f              Dry run
        -v              Verbose
        -r              Read-only mount
        -w              Read-write mount (default)
        -t FSTYPE[,...] Filesystem type(s)
        -O OPT          Mount only filesystems with option OPT (-a only)
-o OPT:
        loop            Ignored (loop devices are autodetected)
        [a]sync         Writes are [a]synchronous
        [no]atime       Disable/enable updates to inode access times
        [no]diratime    Disable/enable atime updates to directories
        [no]relatime    Disable/enable atime updates relative to modification time
        [no]dev         (Dis)allow use of special device files
        [no]exec        (Dis)allow use of executable files
        [no]suid        (Dis)allow set-user-id-root programs
        [r]shared       Convert [recursively] to a shared subtree
        [r]slave        Convert [recursively] to a slave subtree
        [r]private      Convert [recursively] to a private subtree
        [un]bindable    Make mount point [un]able to be bind mounted
        [r]bind         Bind a file or directory [recursively] to another location
        move            Relocate an existing mount point
        remount         Remount a mounted filesystem, changing flags
        ro/rw           Same as -r/-w

There are filesystem-specific -o flags.

~ # mount -av
mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk0p10 on /data failed: No such device
mount: according to /proc/mounts, /dev/block/mmcblk0p9 is already mounted on /cache
mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk0p8 on /system failed: No such device
mount: according to /proc/mounts, /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 is already mounted on /external_sd
~ # ls -l /dev/block/mmcblk0p10
__bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for localtime!
__bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
__bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for posixrules!
brw-------    1 root     root      259,   2 May 11 22:09 /dev/block/mmcblk0p10
~ # cat /etc/fstab
/dev/block/mmcblk0p10 /data f2fs rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p9 /cache ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p8 /system ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /external_sd vfat rw 0 0
~ # mount /dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/system    /system
~ # ls -l /system
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May 11 17:45 addon.d
drwxr-xr-x   38 root     root          4096 May 11 17:45 app
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     shell         8192 May 11 17:45 bin
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3955 Jan  1  2009 build.prop
drwxr-xr-x   16 root     root          4096 May 11 17:45 etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May 11 17:45 fake-libs
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          8192 May 11 17:45 fonts
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May 11 17:46 framework
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root          8192 May 11 17:46 lib
drwxrwx---    2 root     root          4096 May 11 17:45 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 11 17:46 media
drwxr-xr-x   46 root     root          4096 May 11 17:46 priv-app
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       1436220 Jan  1  2009 recovery-from-boot.bak
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 11 17:46 tts
drwxr-xr-x    8 root     root          4096 May 11 17:46 usr
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     shell         4096 May 11 17:46 vendor
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     shell         8192 May 11 17:46 xbin
~ # mount -fv /dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/userdata  /data
~ # ls -l  /data
~ # mkfs.f2fs /data

        F2FS-tools: mkfs.f2fs Ver: 1.4.0 (2014-10-18) [modified by Motorola to reserve space]

Info: Debug level = 0
Info: Label =
Info: Segments per section = 1
Info: Sections per zone = 1
Info: Trim is enabled
        Error: Failed to open the device!
~ #
C:\Users\MarS\Downloads\-Save-\Nook\try\First-200325>adb devices
List of devices attached
3024360011144302        recovery
C:\Users\MarS\Downloads\-Save-\Nook\try\First-200325>adb shell
~ # cat /etc/fstab
/dev/block/mmcblk0p10 /data f2fs rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p9 /cache ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p8 /system ext4 rw 0 0
 /external_sd vfat rw 0 0
~ # mkfs.f2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p10

        F2FS-tools: mkfs.f2fs Ver: 1.4.0 (2014-10-18) [modified by Motorola to reserve space]

Info: Debug level = 0
Info: Label =
Info: Segments per section = 1
Info: Sections per zone = 1
Info: Trim is enabled
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 27000832 (13184 MB)
Info: zone aligned segment0 blkaddr: 512
Info: format version with
  "Linux version 3.0.31-ovation-green+ (green@fatbox1.localnet) (gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC) ) #2 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jun 17 01:18:23 EDT 2013"
Info: Discarding device: 3203800288 sectors
Info: Overprovision ratio = 2%
Info: Overprovision segments = 236 (GC reserved = 108)
Info: format successful
~ # mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p10 /data
mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk0p10 on /data failed: Invalid argument
~ #
C:\Users\MarS\Downloads\-Save-\Nook\try\First-200325>
```

Comment: Still no joy. Tried it all you suggested with the latest `busybox`. The block device formats OK, `fsck` runs clean on it, but it will not mount. Sigh.

Comment: there is something wrong with journaling or disk quota i can see ext4 on your fstab. also check partition size from /proc/partitions is different from file system size (-16384 bytes)

Comment: check this link how to resize file system with resize2fs https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56826844#56826844

Comment: For now, I bypassed the (f2fs?) problem by formatting the partition as ext2. I will try your `resize2fs` approach later. Thanks for all the pointers, alecxs